# Move Server and Upgrade the Application Version Together

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, upgrade

We currently hosts servers in-house.

One has Windows server 2003, and the other has Windows Server 2008 R2.  Both are 32-bit.

Our company decided to move these servers into one server at a server hosting company (meaning the 2003 based applications will be upgraded to windows 2008).

Now a new request was added that in addition to the merge of the two servers, at the time of the merge we should upgrade the application on the server to the new application version - not yet in production or tested, and perform only one set of Tests on the new version in the new server.

I believe that it should be done in two phases, with two sets of testing, to have focus on the issues that will raise.

Can anyone raise the pros and cons of having  it done in one or two phases?

Thanks

Comment: I hope I posted to the right 'exchange' site - If you feel it is better suits another site, please let me know

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you. This is too many changes to make all at once. If anything goes wrong, it could be difficult to pinpoint the problem. And this is where you will run in to more problems.

So let's break down your example. You're moving a server to new location, upgrading the existing app on that server, plus adding a new app that is also being upgraded.

So now there are at least 4 changes being made that the vendor can (and WILL) blame (rightly or wrongly) for any problems.

Oh wait, two apps? Is that two vendors? Twice as much trouble!

So that's all one giant CON for doing this as suggested.

---

You want a PRO?

If everything goes PERFECTLY, you might save some time.

But remember that fixing problems is generally more expensive than proper planning and testing.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I managed to persuade management to allow to upgrade the version in the old servers and when the version seems to be steady, move the new version to the new servers after testing.